# how to run my own C program that prints to std out?

Tags: c, c99

I only used C 2-3 times. Following hello world tutorial did not help. the function should just print to std out console.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_putstr(char* param_1) {
    char *t ;

    for (t = param_1; *t != '\0'; t++) {
        printf("%s", t);
    }

}

int main(){
    my_putstr("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

How to run this program? I do have main to call & test my putstr function.

I do this:

```
gcc file.c -o file
gcc file
```

But it still gives me the error of "main":

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I do have the main function. What's wrong?

Comment: `gcc file.c -o file` followed by `./file`

Comment: `gcc` is a compiler, so once you have used it to create `file` you can just execute `file`.

Comment: To run  the executable: `./file`

Comment: Note that `printf("%s", t);` should be `printf("%c", *t);` Was that in the tutorial?

Comment: @WeatherVane The right statement may be `printf("%s\n", t);`

Comment: @MikeCAT hmm why would you want a string printing function to output `abcbcc` or `abc\nbc\nc\n`?

Comment: Just because it's *called* `my_putstr`, doesn't mean it has to act like `puts` (sans newline). We have no idea what the specification is for that function.

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc file.c -o file
gcc file
```

That second line will try to compile the *executable file* that you created with the first line and, since it's not C source<sup>(a)</sup>, that won't end too well :-)

You need to *run* the file with something like:

```
./file
```

---

And, just as an aside, you should strive to make your programs more readable, such as with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// my_putstr:
//     Output the given string multiple times, each time starting
//     at the next character. So, for "1234", it would output
//     "1234 234 34 4" (without the spaces).

void my_putstr(char *str) {
    // Start at position 0, 1, m2, etc until no more string left.

    for (char *ptr = str; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++) {
        printf("%s", ptr);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    my_putstr("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Changes made:

- Comments are quite handy if you ever come back to the code after some time;
- You should try to avoid simple variable names, use names that make the intent clear (about the only exception are simple `i`, `j`, `k` loop variables;
- The two canonical forms of `main` are `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (though the "or equivalent" phrase in the standard also allows for `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`) or `int main(void)`, you should try to stick with them.

---

By the way, the description in the comments above is an accurate representation of the way the code works. If, instead, you just want to output a string (i.e., *not* the `1234 234 34 4` behaviour), you're probably better off with something like:

```
void my_putstr(char *str) {
    // Output each character, one at a time.

    for (char *ptr = str; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)
        putchar(*ptr);

// Output newline (if desired).

    putchar('\n');
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The `gcc` program is quite capable of taking *other* input file types (like object files, assembler files, and so on) but I'm not sure finished executables are one of those types.

Comment: To add a bit of perspective to this: such invocation is common to interpreted languages where the script "execution" is performed by the interpreter explicitly.